# AngularJS ng-class is ignored by css selectors

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm building an ionic application and recently the dynamic class set through ng-class stopped having any effect. It is still resolved correctly in the HTML, but the selectors just don't work on it.

Here's the template:

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive nav-title-slide-ios7" ng-class="{{ app.style }}">
        <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear"><i class="icon ion-chevron-left"></i> Back</ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>
```

And here's the resulting HTML, which is perfectly fine as far as I can tell:

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive nav-title-slide-ios7 bar bar-header nav-bar disable-user-behavior  no-animation" ng-class="Tallin">
  <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear button back-button ng-hide"><i class="icon ion-chevron-left"></i> Back</ion-nav-back-button>
  <div class="buttons left-buttons"> <span class="">
    <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
  </span></div>
  <h1 ng-bind-html="title" class="title ng-binding" style="left: 51px; right: 51px;">Home</h1>
  <div class="buttons right-buttons"> </div>
</ion-nav-bar>
```

But if I now try to use .Tallin in any CSS selectors, they have no effect. I tried using it as a regular static class, just to validate the selectors, and they work.

This wasn't a problem until recently, but I'm not sure which change started it. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know the relationship between `ng-class` and `class`, but what I do know is that class selectors will *never* match any other attribute in HTML than `class`. If it appears as a value of `ng-class` but not `class` in the generated HTML, it will never match a class selector.

Comment: You are right. I wasn't sure how this works exactly but I checked some examples and AngularJS adds the resolved ng-class to class.

Comment: Remove the curlys. E.g.: `ng-class="app.style">`

Comment: Yeah, that did it. I just figured it out as well. Thanks BoltClock for putting me on the right track

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the {{}}  from class . Write like this `ng-class="app.style"`

Answer (score 2):

`ng-class` expects an expression, and `{{ }}` inserts HTML.

Either do a direct reference

```
<p ng-class="class">Text</p>
```

or have a function on your controller

```
<p ng-class="getClass()">Text</p>
```

or use the object syntax

```
<p ng-class="{ 'red': true }">Text</p>
```

Really, just about anything that is considered an expression can be used.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/1Lbjj8yf/